# More effective way to deduplicate an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

One way of removing duplicates from an array is to convert it to a Set. But if then I'd like to process that further as an array it starts to feel like going in circles - converting the array to a Set, and then back to an array. For example:

```
const arr = [1,2,3,4,1,2,5];
// expected output: "1/2/3/4/5"
const str = [...new Set(arr)].join("/");
```

Is there a more effective way to do it?

Comment: That's probably the most effective way to do it. Not sure why you think it's gross?